# Non-internet radio service for iOS

Tags: gratis, ios, offline, iphone-app, radio

I know that with the earpods/earbuds an iPod can become a radio listener (at least with the 6th Gen iPod Nano) and I understand the same can be done with an iPhone.

What I'm looking for is a **free** app from which I can listen to the radio (i.e. not streaming, but listening to the radio live).

A very important feature is the ability to listen to DAB+ (digital) radio, but I haven't been able to find anything that works with DAB+ without internet.

Summary:

- iOS app that works with iOS 8+
- Is **free**
- Does **not** require internet **(this is *absolutely* essential)**
- Can tune into DAB+ (digital) radio signals (highly desirable)
- Can record/pause live radio (would be nice, but not very important)

Comment: It's going to be tough to find something to do this, the iPhone doesn't have a radio receiver other than WiFi, Bluetooth, and cell. You might be able to do it with an accessory, but that wouldn't meet the 'free' requirement

Comment: This isn't possible - you need additional hardware to tune into these signals, it can't be done by software alone.

Comment: @jonrsharpe; I was afraid of this!  Thanks for the help anyway!